# how to check excel row coloumns with java

Tags: java

i have an excel file with a row name Order ID and it is different product. how to check if the Order ID not a double order

[image]

Comment: Do you want a solution in java or in Excel itself?

Comment: What do you mean by "double order"?

Comment: in Java. i mean in coloumn Double Order show that it's "this is double order" depends on Order ID coloumn